# The best way to handle img with onclick behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I've been developing Frontend software for quite some time now and in my current team I tend to have an argument about very specific implementation for the following task:

We need to have an image (`img`) with certain styles and also when we click on that image we need to show some modal window with additional information. Pretty easy and straightforward one.

So, what I did - I have used img tag and I have applied required styles for shape to this very img and also added onclick to handle modal window appearance, everything works like a charm.

But

I was told that we should never do that, instead - we need to wrap our `img` in `a` tag and apply required styles to the `a` tag and `img` inside and also handle modal window appearance via that `a` tag.

The question I have is why we need to do that?
I've searched web for the answer and didn't find anything related.
Maybe there are some hidden semantics that require us to do it that way?

Anyway, I'd really appreciate if someone can shed a light on that question, do we really need to do that or is this for nothing?

Comment: A simple `<img onclick="foo()">` will be inaccessible via keyboard navigation, you would have to add extra attributes to achieve that. With a link wrapped around the image, you have that kind of accessibility built-in already.